# How to convert 16 bit integer to 8 bit without loosing the data values of the 16 bit integer when the range of 16 bit integer is 0-255

Tags: c++, opencv, 16-bit, 8-bit

```
int samples = 8;  

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (pow(double(2),samples)-1); i++)
{
unsigned int number = i << 1;
}
```

I am doing the coding in C++ using Opencv library.
I want to do bitshift through this and this should be in the range of 0-255 but it is crossing the 255 range and going till 508.

IN Matlab the bitshift operator keeps the range between 0-255. The pattern in matlab is 0,2,4...254,1,3,5...255. But in C++ its going 0,2,4,254,256,258...508. 
I want the same answer as the matlab. Please suggest me some idea to do that.

Comment: This sequence doesn't seem to match the [Matlab documentation for bitshift](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html). Actually I think what is being described is a [rotate left](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/fixedpoint/ref/bitrol.html) with 8-bit width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence `0, 2, 4, 6, ..., 252, 254, 1, 3, 5, ..., 253, 255` (which appears to be what you're after based on the sequence you show) can be generated with:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 257; i = (i == 254) ? 1 : i + 2)
    doSomethingWith (i);
```

There's probably many other ways to generate that sequence as well, including what's probably a more readable dual-loop version, provided you can keep the body of the loops small:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i += 2) doSomethingWith (i); // 0, 2, 4, 6, ..., 254
for (int i = 1; i < 256; i += 2) doSomethingWith (i); // 1, 3, 5, 7, ..., 255
```

Comment: thnks I got the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, `i << 1` is equivalent to `i * 2`, if `i` is an unsigned integer.

This is nothing to do with "converting 16bit integer to 8bit". One way to do that is to mask off all the bits except the lower 8: `(number & 0xFF)` or equivalently `(number % 256)`.

If you multiply by 2 and then do this conversion, you will get `0` after `254`. But that is still not what you want. Your target output has `1` added to the second half.

So, to get that you could use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    number = (i * 2) % 256 + (i >= 128);
```

Comment: Since Matlab does produce a value of 255, it cannot work modulo 255.

Comment: Yeah I saw that afterwards

Comment: This doesn't give the desired sequence  `0,2,4...254,1,3,5...255`, instead it gives `0, 0, 0, ...` ad infinitum. You need to be _adding_ two somehow rather than multiplying by two.

Comment: @paxdiablo, works for me.. http://ideone.com/gBq5Vv . Maybe there was some confusion about variable names

Comment: I can't get at your ideaone code for some reason but I think I understand. You're looping number from 0 to 255 but the variable you construct from it is the expression you gave. That makes sense. I might just add the loop so it makes more sense to me, and matches the variables in the question. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Matlab is doing circular 8-bit shift, when `abcdefgh << 1` becomes `bcdefgha`. C++ has no such thing, but you may simulate it by

```
number = ((i << 1) & 0xff) | (i>> 7);
```